# Java - Object Without New Instance

Tags: java, class, object, hashmap

I have multiple classes in my program, and I'm trying to find a way to use some methods in one of my other classes. Normally I would just do:

```
Class obj = new Class();
```

but that creates a new Instance of it and since I'm using HashMaps, that doesn't work because it creates a new map. I want it to use the same HashMap with stuff already saved in it. What is the best way of doing this?

Edit: Heres an example of the code I'm talking about:
Class #1:

```
public class Foo{
HashMap<String,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String,Integer();
hashmap.put("something", 1);
}
```

Class #2:

```
public class Foo2{
Foo f = new Foo();
f.get("something");
}
```

and nothing shows up for f.get because I created a new version of it...could somebody correct this code for me so I can see what you guys are talking about?

Comment: Pass it as an argument to methods, constructors...

Comment: Can you show the code where you are having actual issue. It's tough to visualize right now.

Comment: You have to share objects already instantiated like `A a= new A(); B b = new B(a);`

Comment: There's a lot of guessing going on in the comments, but I think you might be better off with a general tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing shows up". This isn't even valid code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to share object references

```
public class Main {
    public static class Foo{
        Map<String, Integer> map;
        public Foo(Map<String, Integer> map) {
            this.map = map; // don't create a new object, 
                            // use one that already exists that can be passed as an argument
        }

        public void put(String key, Integer value) {
            map.put(key, value);
        }

        public Integer get(String key) {
            return map.get(key);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> someMap = new HashMap<>();
        someMap.put("aKey", 42);

        Foo foo = new Foo(someMap); // the Foo object now references the map you just created
        System.out.println(foo.get("aKey")); // prints 42
    }
}
```

Here, you create a `Map` and pass a copy of its reference as an argument to your class' constructor. Your class saves this reference and uses it to access the same object.

When sharing objects, it's important to know what you are doing so that updates aren't lost/overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

This is also another possible way to do. Extend hashmap and make the class as singleton.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

class ExtHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<Object,Object> {

    private static HashMap<?, ?> map;

    public static HashMap<?, ?> getInstance() {
        if (map == null) {
            map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        }
        return map;
    }

  private ExtHashMap() {
    super();
  }
}


public class SampleUtil {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        HashMap map = ExtHashMap.getInstance();
        map.put("1", "v1");
        HashMap map1 = ExtHashMap.getInstance();
        map1.put("2", "v2");

        System.out.println(map1.values());
    }
```

}